# Create integers using 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 and +, -

Tags: mathematics, calculation-puzzle, formation-of-numbers

There are numbers $1, 2,3,4,5,6,7$ and signs '$+$' and '$-$'. Using only these numbers and signs, you can compose expressions and calculate the sum (difference). Concatenation operation is not valid.

**Edit.** Each number must be used exactly once and each sign can be used any number of times (from 0 to 7).

The minimum number is $-1-2-3-4-5-6-7 = -28$ and the maximum number is $1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 = 28$, and these can only be obtained in a single way.

**Question:**

1) Is it possible to compose the remaining integers from the range $(-28, 28)$?

2) If an integer from the range $(-28, 28)$ can be composed, how many ways exist?

Comment: Must all numbers be used, or can a subset be used? (e.g. would $7=7$ count?)

Comment: One must use all numbers.

Comment: The restriction is that each number must be used *exactly* once and each sign can be used any number of times? It's not explicitly very clear but this seems to be the only way to make this a non-trivial puzzle.

Comment: @alexanderj93, i have edited the content.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Let's answer the question 2:

> We can write a generating function for the number of combinations. The number $1$ is present either with a $+$ or a $-$, which gives 1 way of making $1$ and 1 way of making $-1$. We will encode these data with a polynomial $z + z^{-1}$. Similarly, we writer $z^2 + z^{-2}$ for the number 2, etc. up to $z^7 + z^{-7}$. The product of all of those polynomials, $G = \prod_{n=1}^7 (z^n + z^{-n})$, is also a polynomial, and the coefficient at any $z^{k}$ is exactly the number of ways to obtain the sum of $k$. (If the term with $z^k$ is not present at all, the coefficient is zero and the sum of $k$ cannot be achieved at all.)

We can immediately answer the question 1 if we notice that

> $G = \prod_{n=1}^7 (z^n + z^{-n})$ can be written as $G = z^{-28} \prod_{n=1}^7 (z^{2n}+1)$. This contains all even powers between $z^{-28}$ and $z^{28}$ (the coefficients are always only a sum of some +1's, i. e. nonzero); so all even numbers can be achieved and no odd number can be achieved.

If there were more than 7 numbers, then it would make sense to try to come up with some algebraic tricks, but

> here we can just put it into Sage to get $$G = z^{28} + z^{26} + z^{24} + 2 \, z^{22} + 2 \, z^{20} + 3 \, z^{18} + 4 \, z^{16} + 5 \, z^{14} + 5 \, z^{12} + 6 \, z^{10} + 7 \, z^{8} + 7 \, z^{6} + 8 \, z^{4} + 8 \, z^{2} + 8 + \frac{8}{z^{2}} + \frac{8}{z^{4}} + \frac{7}{z^{6}} + \frac{7}{z^{8}} + \frac{6}{z^{10}} + \frac{5}{z^{12}} + \frac{5}{z^{14}} + \frac{4}{z^{16}} + \frac{3}{z^{18}} + \frac{2}{z^{20}} + \frac{2}{z^{22}} + \frac{1}{z^{24}} + \frac{1}{z^{26}} + \frac{1}{z^{28}}.$$ Other people have already explained why there can be only even sums. This shows that, out of those, the sums ±28 to ±24 have a single combination of signs, ±22 and ±20 two, ±18 three, ±16 four, ±14 and ±12 five, ±10 six, ±8 and ±6 seven and ±4, ±2 and 0 eight.

Comment: What the Sage means in your answer?

Comment: @Nick, Sage (or better SageMath) is a free/libre open-source computer algebra system. I used that program to expand the product for me. The homepage is https://sagemath.org , if you want to know more.

Comment: I feel disappointed this answer isn't getting more recognition as it's the only current answer that answers the *entire* problem (it answers question 2 and implicitly 1 as well) and does so in a simple and elegant way.

Comment: @ramillies, please add to your text a short answer on the 1st question, then I can tick up.

Answer (score 11):

Question $1$:

> It is **impossible** to construct all integers from $-28$ to $28$.

Proof:

> We can first let all numbers to have positive values. So we have
>  $$+ 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6 + 7 + 8 = 28$$
>  If we want to create another equation, we will **flip** the pluses into minuses. Observe that, if we flip the plus before $x$, then the result will be decreased by $2x$! (For example, flipping $+5$ to $-5$ will create a result of $18$.)

So what can we say from this?

> As each flipping will decrease the result by an even number, therefore the odd integer will **never** appear as a final result!

Question $2$:

> This may not be a "simple" task. Anyway, this can be solved by a [Dynamic Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_programming) approach, but the table will be $28 \times 8$ long. I will not cover this part, but we can have a theory about how to calculate them.

So how many ways to get a final result i.e. $N$?

> You could see from the proof on Question $1$, we can start with all numbers as pluses. This is the only way to get $N=28$. Let me give you an example of how to calculate for $N=10$ as a proof sketch. As flipping the plus before $x$ will decrease the final result by $2x$, note that for $N=10$ we want to decrease the final result by $28-10=18$. Therefore, we have to flip the plus before some numbers such that the sum of those numbers are $\frac{18}{2}=9$! There are several ways e.g. flipping $\{2,7\}$ or $\{4,5\}$ or even $\{2,3,4\}$.

So what's the exact formula?

> If $N$ is odd then the answer is $0$. If $N$ is even, calculate $Y = \frac{28-N}{2}$. The answer is the number of sets consisting integers from $1$ to $7$ such that the sum of these numbers are $Y$.

Comment: Why is the number of sets consisting integers from 1 to 8?  May be from 1 to 7 only?

Comment: @Nick whoops, sorry that was purely a typo, will fix this.

Comment: If the start+end is even, all computed results will be even and if the start+end is odd, all computed results is odd, correct?

Comment: You still have an 8, in your 2nd hidden box.

Comment: @tgm1024--Monicawasmistreated yes that's correct for generalizing the numbers of $1-7$ to any numbers. Anyway ah yes I have that on my second hidden box, but that's ok I guess.. If I code a program, I might extend that to $8$ just for the final check (if the equation results in $N$) :)

Comment: It's a shame that MathJAX doesn't work in spoiler blocks on the mobile site.

Comment: The total number of possibilities is 2^7 = 128, not 28*8 = 224. Either way, that's a laughably small number for a computer, so dynamic programming is not required.  Also your final equation is wrong - it gives a sum of 105 ways to make the non-negative integers, and 301(!?) to make the negative ones.

Comment: @BlueRaja-DannyPflughoeft that's true for smaller number bruteforce is apparently better, anyway the $28 \times 8$ tables consists a lot of $0$s so that's why it might be larger than $128$. (Those $0$s denote the impossibility to get some sum from one to some number.) And oh do you mind to share how to get that number? I'm pretty sure it's correct but it's nice to see why it's not.

Comment: Note that $9!=362,880$ , not $18/2$ ;)

Comment: @athin, I suspect he's referring to the expression possibilities, not the number of final outcomes.  If you have 7 slots, each of which can be of two choices of operations (either plus or minus), you have 2 to the 7th power of possible expressions.  Note that even the first number includes this.  Think in binary if it helps.  The permutation set 128 long is  {+++++++, ++++++-, +++++-+, +++++--, ....., -------}.  There are no "zeros" to worry about.

Comment: @tgm1024--Monicawasmistreated yes that's correct, the thing I asked is why is it 105 and 301, because apparently my formula will give the same result (cmiiw) with Ramillies' answer.

Comment: @athin, You said it "might be larger than 128". It cannot be. 1. Every number must be used, 2. There are 7 slots, and 3. every slot must include one of two operations {+,-}. That's 2^7 (128 expressions, no more, no less, though the # of unique answers is far less). Are you referring to something else? And where are the zeroes? You lost me on both counts.

Comment: @athin, Are you including the *ordering* as part of what defines unique?  1+2 being different from 2+1?.  And by "zeroes" are you referring to the equations that result in zero?

Comment: Lemme clear the misunderstanding @tgm1024--Monica was mistreated. (1) you said the number of possibility is 2^7=128. This is correct. You said mine is 28*8=224. This is not correct. My table size is indeed larger. Table[x][y] will compute how many valid equations such that the sum is x and using only first y integers. That is why here there are so many 0s in the table e.g. Table[10][1] is 0, because you cannot make a valid equation of just 1 to have sum 10. The thing is the Table[x][y] is answering second question -> if you want to know how many solutions for sum = 0, look up Table [0][7].

Comment: @tgm1024--Monica was mistreated one thing you should not is THE SUM OF ALL ENTRIES of Table[x][7] is 2^7. And this is what we care about. (2) You said my final equation is wrong because you said about 105 and 301, how come? My final equation will result precisely the same with Ramillies answer. That's why I asked why do you say so and try to clarify. (3) no ordering as I told above. Lemme know if you're still unclear.

Comment: @athin,  First of all, you have the wrong person in for much of this. I *never* said anything about 28*8=224, or 105, or 301.

Comment: @athin, ok, the table size you're talking about is a general permutation list over *arbitrarily* sized sets of numbers, correct?  We're talking past each other because of meta-commenting.  I'm trying to explain a prior person's comment and you're trying to explain why that comment is to the side of your general equation.  You clearly understand the 2^7 and are building upon that, which is fine.  For me, that's where it starts and ends.

Comment: @tgm1024--Monicawasmistreated oof now I feel bad ><, misthought you because of similar length of the usernames (using mobile mostly). Sorry also for being defensive especially when I tried to defend my answer. The comment section in this answer is too crowded now and I feel if there are any discussions we should head on to chat room. (And perhaps move these comments there too.) But hopefully, it's all good now.

Comment: @athin, sure man, no worries.

Answer (score 6):

Partial answer
a)

> Only even number can be composed.

Reason:

> Changing $+n$ to $-n$ will have a decrease of $2n$, and vice versa, we will have an increase of $2n$. So the parity of the equation will not be changed, which means we can only get even results.

Answer (score 4):

For those interested in a full list of ways, here it is:

> `-28 (1 ways) = -1-2-3-4-5-6-7
>  -26 (1 ways) =  1-2-3-4-5-6-7
>  -24 (1 ways) = -1+2-3-4-5-6-7
>  -22 (2 ways) = -1-2+3-4-5-6-7 =  1+2-3-4-5-6-7
>  -20 (2 ways) = -1-2-3+4-5-6-7 =  1-2+3-4-5-6-7
>  -18 (3 ways) = -1-2-3-4+5-6-7 =  1-2-3+4-5-6-7 = -1+2+3-4-5-6-7
>  -16 (4 ways) = -1-2-3-4-5+6-7 =  1-2-3-4+5-6-7 = -1+2-3+4-5-6-7 =  1+2+3-4-5-6-7
>  -14 (5 ways) = -1-2-3-4-5-6+7 =  1-2-3-4-5+6-7 = -1+2-3-4+5-6-7 = -1-2+3+4-5-6-7
>               =  1+2-3+4-5-6-7
>  -12 (5 ways) =  1-2-3-4-5-6+7 = -1+2-3-4-5+6-7 = -1-2+3-4+5-6-7 =  1+2-3-4+5-6-7
>               =  1-2+3+4-5-6-7
>  -10 (6 ways) = -1+2-3-4-5-6+7 = -1-2+3-4-5+6-7 =  1+2-3-4-5+6-7 = -1-2-3+4+5-6-7
>               =  1-2+3-4+5-6-7 = -1+2+3+4-5-6-7
>   -8 (7 ways) = -1-2+3-4-5-6+7 =  1+2-3-4-5-6+7 = -1-2-3+4-5+6-7 =  1-2+3-4-5+6-7
>               =  1-2-3+4+5-6-7 = -1+2+3-4+5-6-7 =  1+2+3+4-5-6-7
>   -6 (7 ways) = -1-2-3+4-5-6+7 =  1-2+3-4-5-6+7 = -1-2-3-4+5+6-7 =  1-2-3+4-5+6-7
>               = -1+2+3-4-5+6-7 = -1+2-3+4+5-6-7 =  1+2+3-4+5-6-7
>   -4 (8 ways) = -1-2-3-4+5-6+7 =  1-2-3+4-5-6+7 = -1+2+3-4-5-6+7 =  1-2-3-4+5+6-7
>               = -1+2-3+4-5+6-7 =  1+2+3-4-5+6-7 = -1-2+3+4+5-6-7 =  1+2-3+4+5-6-7
>   -2 (8 ways) = -1-2-3-4-5+6+7 =  1-2-3-4+5-6+7 = -1+2-3+4-5-6+7 =  1+2+3-4-5-6+7
>               = -1+2-3-4+5+6-7 = -1-2+3+4-5+6-7 =  1+2-3+4-5+6-7 =  1-2+3+4+5-6-7
>    0 (8 ways) =  1-2-3-4-5+6+7 = -1+2-3-4+5-6+7 = -1-2+3+4-5-6+7 =  1+2-3+4-5-6+7
>               = -1-2+3-4+5+6-7 =  1+2-3-4+5+6-7 =  1-2+3+4-5+6-7 = -1+2+3+4+5-6-7
>    2 (8 ways) = -1+2-3-4-5+6+7 = -1-2+3-4+5-6+7 =  1+2-3-4+5-6+7 =  1-2+3+4-5-6+7
>               = -1-2-3+4+5+6-7 =  1-2+3-4+5+6-7 = -1+2+3+4-5+6-7 =  1+2+3+4+5-6-7
>    4 (8 ways) = -1-2+3-4-5+6+7 =  1+2-3-4-5+6+7 = -1-2-3+4+5-6+7 =  1-2+3-4+5-6+7
>               = -1+2+3+4-5-6+7 =  1-2-3+4+5+6-7 = -1+2+3-4+5+6-7 =  1+2+3+4-5+6-7
>    6 (7 ways) = -1-2-3+4-5+6+7 =  1-2+3-4-5+6+7 =  1-2-3+4+5-6+7 = -1+2+3-4+5-6+7
>               =  1+2+3+4-5-6+7 = -1+2-3+4+5+6-7 =  1+2+3-4+5+6-7
>    8 (7 ways) = -1-2-3-4+5+6+7 =  1-2-3+4-5+6+7 = -1+2+3-4-5+6+7 = -1+2-3+4+5-6+7
>               =  1+2+3-4+5-6+7 = -1-2+3+4+5+6-7 =  1+2-3+4+5+6-7
>   10 (6 ways) =  1-2-3-4+5+6+7 = -1+2-3+4-5+6+7 =  1+2+3-4-5+6+7 = -1-2+3+4+5-6+7
>               =  1+2-3+4+5-6+7 =  1-2+3+4+5+6-7
>   12 (5 ways) = -1+2-3-4+5+6+7 = -1-2+3+4-5+6+7 =  1+2-3+4-5+6+7 =  1-2+3+4+5-6+7
>               = -1+2+3+4+5+6-7
>   14 (5 ways) = -1-2+3-4+5+6+7 =  1+2-3-4+5+6+7 =  1-2+3+4-5+6+7 = -1+2+3+4+5-6+7
>               =  1+2+3+4+5+6-7
>   16 (4 ways) = -1-2-3+4+5+6+7 =  1-2+3-4+5+6+7 = -1+2+3+4-5+6+7 =  1+2+3+4+5-6+7
>   18 (3 ways) =  1-2-3+4+5+6+7 = -1+2+3-4+5+6+7 =  1+2+3+4-5+6+7
>   20 (2 ways) = -1+2-3+4+5+6+7 =  1+2+3-4+5+6+7
>   22 (2 ways) = -1-2+3+4+5+6+7 =  1+2-3+4+5+6+7
>   24 (1 ways) =  1-2+3+4+5+6+7
>   26 (1 ways) = -1+2+3+4+5+6+7
>   28 (1 ways) =  1+2+3+4+5+6+7`

The above was generated using this Java code:

```
Map<Integer, List<Integer>> resultFreq = new TreeMap<>();
for (int signMask = 0; signMask < (1 << 7); signMask++) {
    int result = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        if ((signMask & (1 << i)) == 0)
            result += i + 1;
        else
            result -= i + 1;
    }
    resultFreq.computeIfAbsent(result, k -> new ArrayList<>()).add(signMask);
}

StringBuilder buf = new StringBuilder();
for (Entry<Integer, List<Integer>> entry : resultFreq.entrySet()) {
    buf.setLength(0);
    buf.append(String.format("%3d (%d ways)", entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().size()));
    for (int signMask : entry.getValue()) {
        buf.append(" = ");
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            buf.append((signMask & (1 << i)) != 0 ? '-' : i > 0 ? '+' : ' ').append(i + 1);
    }
    System.out.println(buf);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Because everyone made mathematical proof. I've decided I'm going to try adding a little value on the puzzle and give a solution for each possible case even if it is not part of the puzzle. I also like seeing it *'solved'*, not only formulas :)

$$-28 = -1-2-3-4-5-6-7$$
$$-26 = 1-2-3-4-5-6-7$$
$$-24 = -1+2-3-4-5-6-7$$
$$-22 = -1-2+3-4-5-6-7$$
$$-20 = -1-2-3+4-5-6-7$$
$$-18 = -1-2-3-4+5-6-7$$
$$-16 = -1-2-3-4-5+6-7$$
$$-14 = -1-2-3-4-5-6+7$$
$$-12 = 1-2-3-4-5-6+7$$
$$-10 = -1+2+3+4-5-6-7$$
$$-8 = -1-2-3+4-5+6-7$$
$$-6 = -1-2-3-4+5+6-7$$
$$-4 = 1-2-3-4+5+6-7$$
$$-2 = -1-2-3-4-5+6+7$$
$$0 = 1-2-3-4-5+6+7$$
$$2 = 1-2+3+4-5-6+7$$
$$4 = -1-2-3+4+5-6+7$$
$$6 = 1-2-3+4+5-6+7$$
$$8 = -1-2-3-4+5+6+7$$
$$10 = 1-2-3-4+5+6+7$$
$$12 = -1-2+3+4-5+6+7$$
$$14 = 1-2+3+4-5+6+7$$
$$16 = -1-2-3+4+5+6+7$$
$$18 = 1-2-3+4+5+6+7$$
$$20 = 1+2+3-4+5+6+7$$
$$22 = -1-2+3+4+5+6+7$$
$$24 = 1-2+3+4+5+6+7$$
$$26 = -1+2+3+4+5+6+7$$
$$28 = 1+2+3+4+5+6+7$$

Comment: I counted 67 solutions, in your answer 29.

Comment: @Nick, I know! Please look at left column and text paragraph ;)

Comment: @Nick There are $2^7=128$ ways to set the +/- options. How do you count 67?

Comment: @danielmathias, you are right. I was disappointed by last sentence from the Ramillies's answer.

Answer (score -1):

28 just 1 way 1+2+3+4+5+6+7=28
27 is 2 ways 2+3+4+5+6+7=27
1+2+3+4+5+6+7-1=27
26 is 3 ways 1+3+4+5+6+7=26
2+3+4+5+6+7-1=26
1+2+3+4+5+6+7-2=26
Like thak you can create all...

Comment: You don't use all numbers for odd sums.